# The journey Ijon Tichy

Tags: novel, stanislaw-lem

In what journey does Ijon Tichy get to the planet where after the destruction everything is restored quickly, it looks like a 3d printer?

Comment: Are you referring to the books or the short-lived TV series?

Comment: @Valorum, i mean book

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the 14th journey in the Star Diaries. The story plays out on a planet ("Enteropia" in the German translation) that is plagued by frequent meteor impacts. Everything that is destroyed, including people, is immediately replaced by an exact copy.

However the procees does quite resemble 3D printing, IIRC replacements (at least for people) are actually delivered by mail.

That's for the book, obviously.

Comment: In the second book there is also a brief mention to a planet that is so crowded that, for sleeping, people is disintegrated and stored as dust and when they have to be waken up they are reconstructed from the dust, but I think your option is a better fit.

Comment: And the short movie version actually combines these two planets into one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xO9ppicjlFg