# Story about a man who gets reloaded from a save point after dying

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find the name of the story about an adventure of some guy who visits a planet where upon arrival his state as a human being is saved. As he progresses through the planet he keeps finding imminent death, and when he dies he is loaded back from the saved state. I just remember he was hit by an asteroid once or twice, he was shot too, or something of the kind.

My suspicion is that Stanislav Lem might have written this story since it was fiction, fantasy, comedy, and lots more.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177212/the-journey-ijon-tichy).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The journey Ijon Tichy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/177212/the-journey-ijon-tichy)

Comment: We don't close story id questions as duplicates unless both questions have accepted answers.